# Python: If element not in list, add to new list

Tags: python

I have an ugly looking function and figured there must be a more Pythonic way of doing this (the capital letter variables are strings):

```
def get_missing_header_fields(header):
    missing_fields = []
    if FIRST_NAME not in header:
        missing_fields.append(FIRST_NAME)
    if LAST_NAME not in header:
        missing_fields.append(LAST_NAME)
    if EMAIL not in header:
        missing_fields.append(EMAIL)
    if PHONE not in header:
        missing_fields.append(PHONE)
    if ADDRESS not in header:
        missing_fields.append(ADDRESS)
    if COMPANY not in header:
        missing_fields.append(COMPANY)
    if TITLE not in header:
        missing_fields.append(TITLE)
    return missing_fields
```

Any recs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a comprehension

```
def get_missing_header_fields(header):
    # Completing the tuple is an exercise for the reader
    fields = (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ..., TITLE)
    return [field for field in fields if field not in header]
```

or even a set

```
def get_missing_header_fields(header):
    # Completing the tuple is an exercise for the reader
    fields = set(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ..., TITLE)
    return list(fields - set(header))
```

Comment: OK, that just changes the last line

Answer (score 4):

You can use sets for this:

```
FIELDS = set([FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, etc...])

def get_missing_header_fields(header):
  return FIELDS.difference(header)
```

Sets are `iterables` and support membership tests which is usually sufficient for most usecases. If you really need a list just construct one: `list(FIELDS.difference(header))`